# Redux Persist, rehydrate not working on an android

Tags: react-native, react-redux, expo

I have an app base on React Native & Expo. My app & redux persist works fine until I kill an app process. After relaunch redux persist can't rehydrate (no errors) and all data saved in store is lost.

Does anyone have an idea what I do wrong?
Or maybe I didn't set something?

Here is my store config.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';

import appReducer from '../scenes/App/app.reducer';
//...other reducers
import actionReducer from '../lib/managers/action.reducer';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  app: appReducer,
  //...other reducers
  action: actionReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  blacklist: ['log', 'action'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

function configureStore() {
  return createStore(persistedReducer, composeEnhancers());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you bootstrap your app? Are you using *react-native-navigation* ? Or other rooters approach?

This config does not seem incorrect, but maybe the issue is in how your wrap your root (maybe you should share that bit too)

see from [redux-persist documentation](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) on how to wrap your root with `PersistGate`:

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```